# PTIJ: Why do we make a Lulav holder?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemara says:

> אין עושין מצות חבילות חבילות
>
> One does not make mitzvot into bundles.

But I've seen lots of people do just that: They put the four species into a bundle.

ואם תומר, and if you'll say:

The issue is *making* a Mitzva into a bundle, not *putting* the Mitzvah into a bundle.

You can't say that since the bundle is made from Lulav leaves. So we quite literally made a Mitzvah into a bundle.

Oh, and there are some who only make a bundle out of the Lulav, without even making a basket.

[image]

That should *definitely* be an issue.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: VTC as not Purim Torah

Comment: @DoubleAA Ummm... You think that this is a _real_ question?

Comment: If I removed the disclaimer, would you be able to tell it wasn't?

Comment: Yes because he is making a pun of חבילות חבילות @DoubleAA

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel What's the pun? Why isn't picking all four up together a violation of that rule? Can you answer that real question for me?

Comment: @DoubleAA From the way that he addresses the serious question, answering it by posing the ridiculous Purim Torah interpretation (turning the lulav into a bundle), it's clear he means it as PTIJ. Consider https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1990/, whose guidelines the OP is definitely following.

Comment: @DonielF That post is in the context of the old PTIJ guidelines. I don't think there's any such ambiguity in the current formulation.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not a violation of Ein Osin Mitzvos because that is what the Mitzvah is. The Mitzvah is to pick them up together. The same way it's not Ein Osim Mitzvos Chavilos to eat Matza and Marror together according to Hillel

Comment: @Leitz that's only according to R Yehuda that Lulav Tzarikh Egged. What about the Chachamim who we Paskin like? (See how someone might ask this question seriously even if you think you know an answer?)

Comment: @DoubleAA (and @Leitz) isn't this not at all relevant to אין עושין מצות חבילות because it is all one מצוה?

Comment: @yez is it? You can say four blessings on the four parts if you take them separately. The fact that you can come up with answers doesn't make it not a realistic question.

Comment: @DoubleAA I recall that the Gemara is explicit that taking 3 מינים is not a מצוה and would only be done as a zecher, although it's been a while since I learned this. We make berachos on zechiros, so beracha isn't really a proof.

Comment: But in any event, that seemingly isn't the Purim-ness of this. You and I and Leitz all agree, I think, that making tefillin into a basket isn't the issur of חבילות חבילות, which is essentially the misinterpretation being employed here.

Comment: @yez that's three without the fourth. If you have the fourth across the street you can take three now and one later. (Except according to tosfot)

Comment: @DoubleAA Fine, but at the end of the day they are all essential components of the same _mitzvah_. If you don't take all four, three is nothing. So you have not bundled together separate _mitzvos_.

Comment: @yez I'm not saying there isn't an answer to the question. Just that it's a question. The fact that we are citing Gemaras and tosfots etc. seriously is proof to that

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm fine with that. But as much as I enjoy debating with you, [this remains true](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100957/ptij-why-do-we-make-a-lulav-holder?noredirect=1#comment337149_100957)

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to punctuate it is

> אין עושין מצוות חבילות - חבילות
>
> One should not make bundles of *mitzvos* into bundles

So, taking just one *mitzvah*, like the lulav, and making it into a bundle is perfectly fine. If you were to take your whole lulav-bundle and wrap a lulav with that, using a bundle of *mitzvos* to bundle, that would be a problem.

Comment: +1. in this case you are wrapping a bundle of mitzvos-daled minim- with a mitzvah-lulav leaf-

Answer (score 5):

The Gemara didn't need to repeat the word חבילות must be אין מיעוט אחר מיעוט אלא לרבות and the Gemara is teaching you that if you are bundling them many times it is mutar.

So if you don't have a basket you are fine because you bundle it several times and the problem is only if you have one basket.

Answer (score 3):

In Aramaic the word אין means yes. The PTIJ explanation of this is Yes we make Mitzvas into bundles.